# Quiero enviar el ID de la Factura a un archivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de facturacion. Actualmente todo lo tengo generado con Ajax y tengo este codigo que genera la tabla que me muestra la informacion de la tabla facturas de mi base de datos:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/api.php?accion=ver-lista-facturas",
    method: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(respuesta){
        for (var i=0; i<respuesta.length;i++){
            $('#table-facturas').append(
                '<tr>'+
                '<th class="text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">'+respuesta[i].idfacturas+'</th>'+
                '<td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">'+respuesta[i].nombreTienda+'</td>'+
                '<td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">'+respuesta[i].fecha_factura+'</td>'+
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Ver Factura</button></td>'+
            '</tr>'
            );
        }  


    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Lo que me gustaria hacer es enviar, al darle click al boton "Ver Factura", el idfacturas que aparece en el th al archivo php para que con este se pueda generar una factura con fpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un ajax de tipo post que hace esto. Crea una función que recibe el id de la factura como parámetro.

```js
function enviarID(id){
var parametros = {"idFactura":id};
  $.ajax({
    data:parametros,
    url: "__archivo php para crear pdf__",
    type:"post",
    success:function(respuesta){
        
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
}
```

En el botón llama la función con el onclick y pásala el idfacturas.
En el php recibe el id con $_POST